# Is it correct to write "He takes part in a project"?

Tags: prepositions

I searched for an answer at this site, but didn't find it. Is it correct to write "He takes part **in** a project"? Is "takes part **in**" correct in the aforementioned sentence? Or should other preposition be used instead of "**in**"? The meaning of the sentence is that someone works **on** a project, i.e. he is a member of the project's team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, *take part in* is proper. The right preposition to use with an idiom such as *take part* is often somewhat arbitrary and determined by convention rather than by strict adherence to the definition or "rules" of the preposition. *Take part* may be derived from or otherwise related to *partake* or *participate*. Both words take *in* as a preposition, which may have led to *take part in*.